# Fetch mails from another mailbox in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, gmail

I am trying to fetch mails from another mailbox (xxx@domail.com or xxx@gmail.com) in google-app-engine.
I don't want to read mails from appspotmail box as it is being used for different purpose.

Is there any efficient way in which i can make this happen.

Comment: Forward your mail to appspot.

Comment: isnt there anything way in which i can read from other mailbox

Comment: See the answers below. Forwarding (instead of imap polling) to a special app engine address is very easy. See also the answer of Peter Knego below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. You could read an inbox via POP/IMAP, but this [requires a bit of coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916679/imap-using-oauth2-on-app-engine). You also need to have Outgoing Sockets API enabled, which requires you to have a paid app. This approach is async, which means you will constantly need to poll for new messages.
2. Forward emails to a new appspotmail address (you can have many). This is pretty easy, especially since you already process incoming emails. Since you can have multiple accounts, e.g. xyz@yourappid.appspotmail.com, you can distinguish between them in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imap+oauth to read email from a google address. If you google it the very first result is what you need. https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview